# Unix how to concatenate lines based on pattern

Tags: unix, awk

I want to join lines in a file as below.

Input

```
01EPH087362 SHHFHDH 3673
63737
Dhdhj
01EPH636363 DHHDH 
3637737
Hshshhd
01EPH7373838 HDJJDJ
```

Output

```
01EPH087362 SHHFHDH 3673 63737 Dhdhj
01EPH636363 DHHDH  3637737Hshshhd
01EPH7373838 HDJJDJ
```

I want the output as above; basically every line should start with 01EPH.

I have awk and sed but no luck. Please help if you know.

Comment: In your output, the use of spaces to separate joined lines is inconsistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Input**

```
$ cat f
01EPH087362 SHHFHDH 3673
63737
Dhdhj
01EPH636363 DHHDH 
3637737
Hshshhd
01EPH7373838 HDJJDJ
```

**Output**

```
$ awk '(s=/^01EPH/) && NR>1{print ""}{printf("%s%s",(s?"":" "),$0)}END{print ""}' f
01EPH087362 SHHFHDH 3673 63737 Dhdhj
01EPH636363 DHHDH  3637737 Hshshhd
01EPH7373838 HDJJDJ
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '/^01EPH/{if (NR>1) print buf; buf=$0; next} {buf = buf OFS $0} END{print buf}' file
01EPH087362 SHHFHDH 3673 63737 Dhdhj
01EPH636363 DHHDH  3637737 Hshshhd
01EPH7373838 HDJJDJ
```

Answer (score 2):

My take:

```
awk '
    /^01EPH/ {printf "%s%s", nl, $0; nl = "\n"; next} 
    {printf " %s", $0} 
    END {print ""}
' file
```

Answer (score 2):

another `awk`

```
$ $ awk 'NR>1 && /^01EPH/ {print ""} 
                          {printf "%s", $0 OFS} 
         END              {print ""}' file

01EPH087362 SHHFHDH 3673 63737 Dhdhj
01EPH636363 DHHDH  3637737 Hshshhd
01EPH7373838 HDJJDJ
```

add newline when pattern matches (except first line) and at the end, otherwise append lines...

Answer (score 2):

@suyog: Could you please try following too and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk '{printf("%s%s",($0 ~ /^01E/ && NR>1)?ORS:NR>1?FS:"",$0)} END{print ""}' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
01EPH087362 SHHFHDH 3673 63737 Dhdhj                                                                                                                                           
01EPH636363 DHHDH  3637737 Hshshhd                                                                                                                                             
01EPH7373838 HDJJDJ
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/^01EPH/ { if (record != "") print record; record = ""; pad = "" }
     { record = record pad $0; pad = " " }
     END { if (record != "") print record }'
```

If the line starts `01EPH`, print the saved information, if there is any, and empty the saved information and the padding.

On every line, add the pad and the new line to the saved information; set the pad to a blank.

At the end, print the saved record if there is anything in it.

This even miraculously preserves the double space between `DHHDH` and `3637737Hshshhd` because there is a trailing blank on the line ending `DHHDH`.

Output:

```
01EPH087362 SHHFHDH 3673 63737 Dhdhj
01EPH636363 DHHDH  3637737 Hshshhd
01EPH7373838 HDJJDJ
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have a file with only \n line-endings, you could use

```
sed 's/^01EPH/\r&/;$s/$/\r/' inputfile | tr -d "\n" | tr "\r" "\n"
```

The first part of sed inserts a `\r` before each `01EPH`. The second part appends one at the end so that the last line will end with a linefeed too.
Now remove the original linefeeds and replace the marked ones with linefeeds.
It goes through the file 3 times, so any `awk` solution will be better for a large file, but I just wanted to show `tr`with `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is pure Bash (plus `printf`) to do this just for giggles:

```
while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n $line ]]; do 
    if [[ "$line" =~ ^01EPH ]]; then
        printf "%s%s" "$pad" "$line" 
        pad=$'\n'
    else
        printf " %s" "$line"
    fi
done <file
```

Here is a Perl slurp solution:

```
perl -0777 -ne 'while (/(^01EPH.*?)(?=^01EPH|\z)/gms) {($st=$1)=~s/\n/ /g; print "$st\n" }' file
```

In both cases, `awk` is probably better...

Answer (score -2):

One liner:

```
tr '\n' ' ' < file.txt | sed s/01EPH/\\n01EPH/g
```

`tr '\n' ' ' < file.txt` - makes one string

`sed s/01EPH/\\n01EPH/g` - prefix **01EPH** by newline

Comment: That would insert newlines before every `01EPH` even if it occurred in the middle of another string in the middle of a line. The `tr` also removes all newlines which turns it's output into a non-text-file (per POSIX) so what any given sed or any other tool does with that is undefined behavior and so YMMV with that. Best case it also adds a leading newline and a trailing blank character and does not provide a terminating newline so YMMV with what you can do with that output. In short, don't do it.

Comment: You're right. Anyway I'll keep this answer, just in case. Hopefully people read comments:)